# Extracting model equation and other data from 'glm' function in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I've made a logistic regression to combine two independent variables in `R`, using `pROC` package and I obtain this:

```
 summary(fit)

Call: glm(formula = Case ~ X + Y, family = "binomial", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
  Min       1Q     Median     3Q      Max  
-1.5751  -0.8277  -0.6095   1.0701   2.3080  

Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.153731   0.538511  -0.285 0.775281    
X           -0.048843   0.012856  -3.799 0.000145 ***
Y            0.028364   0.009077   3.125 0.001780 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 287.44  on 241  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 260.34  on 239  degrees of freedom
AIC: 266.34

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

>     fit

Call:  glm(formula = Case ~ X + Y, family = "binomial", data = data)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)       X            Y  
   -0.15373     -0.04884      0.02836  

Degrees of Freedom: 241 Total (i.e. Null);  239 Residual
Null Deviance:      287.4 
Residual Deviance:  260.3        AIC: 266.3
```

Now I need to extract some information from this data and I'm not sure about how to do it. First, I need the model equation: suppose that fit is a combined predictor called `CP`; could it be `CP=-0.15-0.05X+0.03Y`?

Then, the resulting combined predictor from the regression should present a median value, so that I can compare median from the two groups `Case` and `Controls` which I used to make the regression (in other words, my `X` and `Y` variables are N-dimensional with `N = N1+N2`, where `N1 = Number of Controls`, for which `Case=0`, and `N2 = Number of Cases`, for which `Case=1`).

Comment: IMHO, this question better fits _Cross Validated_ or _StackOverflow_ SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

In order to extract some data from the fitted `glm` model object, you need to figure out where that data resides (use documentation and `str()` for that). Some data might be available from the `summary.glm` object, while more detailed data is available from the `glm` object itself. For extracting model parameters, you can use `coef()` function or direct access to the structure.

**UPDATE:**

From Princeton's* introduction to R course's website, [GLM section](http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html) - see for details & examples:

> The functions that can be used to extract results from the fit
>   include
>
> ```
> - 'residuals' or 'resid', for the deviance residuals
> - 'fitted' or 'fitted.values', for the fitted values (estimated probabilities)
> - 'predict', for the linear predictor (estimated logits)
> - 'coef' or 'coefficients', for the coefficients, and
> - 'deviance', for the deviance.
> ```
>
> Some of these functions have optional arguments; for example, you can
>   extract five different types of residuals, called "deviance",
>   "pearson", "response" (response - fitted value), "working" (the
>   working dependent variable in the IRLS algorithm - linear predictor),
>   and "partial" (a matrix of working residuals formed by omitting each
>   term in the model). You specify the one you want using the type
>   argument, for example residuals(lrfit,type="pearson").

*) More accurately, this website is by Germán Rodríguez from Princeton University.

Comment: given that 
    fit-< glm(formula = Case ~ X + Y, family = "binomial", data = data)

what is fitted(fit)? Could it be what i'm looking for?

Comment: @Ciochi: No. In your example above, a fitted `glm` model object would be the `fit` object. See UPDATE section in my answer.

Comment: @Ciochi: So, my suggestion is to use standard access functions (see UPDATE) for extracting traditional information and `str()` and low-level (direct) access (via `$`), if you need other information, not accessible via high-level functions. I hope that this clarifies things.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i appreciate it. I've already read the Update section you've added, but i still dont get it, mostly because i'm pretty noob on statistics, i just use basic stuff like t-test etc. Indeed, i dont get what the fit object is. Is it a new variable?

Comment: @Ciochi: You're welcome. Feel free to accept/upvote my answer, if it is helpful. Yes, `fit` is new variable that gets created and initialized with the return value of the `glm()` function (the return value is an object of class `glm`).

Comment: I still have some problems in getting the value of this new variable fit. Reading elsewhere it seems to me that this variable fit is a variable of estimated probabilities, thus ranging from 0 to 1, as the values i get when i run fitted(fit).

Comment: @Ciochi: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what your current issue is.

Comment: The problem is that i need to use those values for an upcoming proceeding. Being the new variable fit called Z, i need to to present data as Z: Controls vs Cases, mean ± sd vs mean ± sd, P<0.01, for example.

Comment: @Ciochi: I think that you might receive more attention and help with this question at the _Cross Validated_ SE site. I can ask local moderator to migrate it, if you want.